# Download a file in amazon s3 account to another s3 account using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-s3

I have hosted my website on amazon. I want my clients to allow following functionality.

User inputs valid credentials and file path of their s3 account to my website. My website download that file in user's amazon s3 account location to my amazon s3 account. I need to do this using cake php 1.2 and these file can be over 10GB most of the time. Is their any recommended way of doing this? I Google this and didn't find good solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the AWS PHP SDK. You can include the sdk as a vendor lib in cakephp.

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/

More specifically they have a function that allows you to copy a file from one bucket to another.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/copy_object

Comment: According to this it allows us to copy a files in same s3 region right? IF it allows to copy from one s3 account to another s3 account where do I need to give specify the credentials?